# Symfony2 deploy - authorization error

Tags: symfony

I am deploying `symfony2` application. I have already been able to log in successfully but now I have authorization problems.

After login debuger shows that my roles are:

```
Roles   [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER]
```

Security.yml is:

```
ROLE_USER:    ROLE_VIEW
```

However when I try to access any of my webpages (e.g.     ****.pl/app/choosebook/1) I got:

```
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this document.
```

This is even though my controller looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("app/choosebook/{inp_book_id}", name="app_choosebook")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_VIEW')")
 */
 public function choosebookAction($inp_book_id)
```

My .htaccess at root of directory is:

```
//Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

What may be the source of problem? I think that it may have something to do with .htaccess as I am redirecting traffic from root directory to /web/.

Comment: Are you sure the URL you're accessing is behind the firewall you get your user authorized against? Please, supply your `security.yml` for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved out this problem.

It was connected with my host (home.pl) settings. At the beginning I have redirected traffic from `/` (root) directory to `/web/`. This however resulted in problems with setting session. Therefore I was forced to map domain directly to `/web/` directory instead, and disabling separation of webpages.